# unique_ptr<Expression>::Operator '=' is inaccessible

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, std, unique-ptr

Summary: Why is the '=' assignment operator inaccessible with two objects of the same type `std::unique_ptr<Expression, std::default_delete<Expression>>`?
Mind you, in the code the types are written `std::unique_ptr<Expression>` but expand to the former in the IntelliSense error.

### Info

IDE - Running Visual C++ 2010
OS - Windows Vista
Target - Console Application attempting to use what's implemented of C++11

### Some Background

I've been provided an example of an expression evaluator in C++ which apparently is up to the new standard alright, because what should be solid code is giving me errors and I'm guessing it's because VC++ has no support for the feature. The first error I got was with the 'make_unique' method, VC++ said "identifier doesn't exist", so I implemented it myself

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());
} // Basically just wrapping 'new'? Not sure why
```

Found a better one online but it gave errors, this ^ gives no errors. All I did was remove the ...Args template parameter. I have a set of Expression classes that looks like this:

```
class Expression {
    virtual ~Expression() {}
};

class BinaryExpression : public Expression {
public:
     std::unique_ptr<Expression> lhs;
     std::unique_ptr<Expression> rhs;
     virtual char GetType() const = 0; // +,-,/,*
};
// Then MulExpression, DivExpression, PlusExpression, blah blah
```

Now here's where I get the error, mind you, ParseAdditiveExpression()'s return type is

```
// expr, lhs, and rhs are all of the same type
std::unique_ptr<Expression>:
auto rhs = ParseAdditiveExpression();
auto expr = make_unique<MulExpression>(); // Tried using: std::unique_ptr<Expression> expr;
expr->lhs = lhs; // Trouble Makers
expr->rhs = rhs; // All produce
lhs = expr; // The same errors
```

The error is as follows:

```
1   IntelliSense: "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx> &) [with _Ty=Expression, _Dx=std::default_delete<Expression>]" 
(declared at line 2352 of "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\memory")
is inaccessible 
c:\users\s_miller47\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\_vc++\powercalc\mathparser.h  133
```

Now, I think this may have something to do with the 'const' at the right size of the '=', but I've tried changing the functions return type to fit, with * or & after the return type, tried de-referencing ('*') the value before I set it to expr->lhs, even tried ('&')

So if the operator is inaccessible how do I fix it? Do I have to define the operator myself? (nonsense) Well, here is the full code: [PasteBin Source Code Link](http://pastebin.com/Ys2tWxcc)

Comment: `unique_ptr` is not copyable. Try `expr->lhs = std::move(lhs);`.

Comment: "not sure why": [Exception safety](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, it seems pretty obvious now considering 'unique' *facepalm*. Lol and I give all this info thinking the problem was complicated or something, thanks for the help.

Comment: Wow, forget to put ONE thing in a body and get downvoted. Heh, oh well :p
I think the rest of my post was well formatted, lol could give me credit for not just saying "uh hey i have operator inaccessible error whats to do naow!!???"

Comment: Upvoted to compensate. It's a well asked and meaningful question that someone searching for might find if they have the same problem. The fact that the answer is simple does not invalidate the question.

Comment: @J99 Well I appreciate it :) I just know now to make sure my compiler/IntelliSense errors go in a block as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is non-assignable and non-copyable. If you want to make such assignment, you will need to use `std::move()`:

```
lhs = std::move(expr);
```

Comment: Such a simple solution to what I thought was not a simple problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: *"is non-assignable and non-copyable"* It's move-assignable though.

Answer (score 5):

Instantiations of `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied; they can only be moved (hence the "unique"). So, for assignment, you have to say that you want to move the pointer:

```
lhs = std::move(expr);
```

Comment: Yeah, lol, I guess I didn't quite think about 'unique' to hard when I was trying to **copy** it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that unique_ptr, as the name suggests, maintains a **unique** pointer. That's one of the main reasons why autp_ptr was deprecated: it actually "moved" the pointer in an assignment, instead of copying it. This is considered a bad thing; if you do "a=b" then you expect to have two reasonably identical objects "a" and "b". You don't expect "b" to be emptied out.

Thus, to maintain the uniqueness of the pointer, unique_ptr doesn't allow any form of copying.